# wamp reinstall - how to replace new files with old files

Tags: drupal-6, wamp, wampserver

I formatted my hard drive, and saved the full folder of my WAMP  `(c:\wamp)`.

I then reinstalled Windows and the installed the exact same WAMP server, and then just replaced all the contents in `c:\wamp` with my previous version.

I was hoping this would work.

But the wamp indicator just stays yellow now, and when I try to run localhost it just says,

> Could not execute menu (internal error).
>
> [Exception] Could not execute run action.  The directory name is
>   invalid.

Can someone tell me how best to get my previous WAMP version up and running??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised when I reinstalled WAMP I had a slightly different version. When I made certain that the new WAMP version was idential the previous WAMP version, I could easily replace the new install content with all my previous content.